# why there is no template argument in __enable_shared_from_this_helper in gcc/libstdc++

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, libstdc++

i am reading the stl code for enable_shared_from_this, it is in the gcc-4.9.2\libstdc++-v3\include\bits\shared_ptr.h. Then i saw this:

```
template<typename _Tp1>
friend void
__enable_shared_from_this_helper(const __shared_count<>& __pn,
                 const enable_shared_from_this* __pe,
                 const _Tp1* __px) noexcept
{
  if (__pe != 0)
    __pe->_M_weak_assign(const_cast<_Tp1*>(__px), __pn);
}
```

My question is, why there is no template argument for **const enable_shared_from_this* __pe**? How does it work when shared_ptr constructor calls __enable_shared_from_this_helper with a pointer to class A, where A derived from enable_shared_from_this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is known as an **injected class name**. The *C++ standard* allows this for example in 14.6.1:

> Like normal (non-template) classes, class templates have an
>   injected-class-name (Clause 9). The injected- class-name can be used
>   as a template-name or a type-name. When it is used with a
>   template-argument-list, as a template-argument for a template
>   template-parameter, or as the final identifier in the elaborated-type-
>   specifier of a friend class template declaration, it refers to the
>   class template itself. **Otherwise, it is equivalent to the
>   template-name followed by the template-parameters of the class
>   template enclosed in <>.**

If you look at the source code of *shared_ptr_base.h*, you can see that the template arguments are required because it is a **outside the class**:

```
00730   // Friend of __enable_shared_from_this.
00731   template<_Lock_policy _Lp, typename _Tp1, typename _Tp2>
00732     void
00733     __enable_shared_from_this_helper(const __shared_count<_Lp>&,
00734                      const __enable_shared_from_this<_Tp1,
00735                      _Lp>*, const _Tp2*);
```

But in *shared_ptr.h*, the definition is **inside the class**:

```
00473   template<typename _Tp>
00474     class enable_shared_from_this
00475     {

...

00502       template<typename _Tp1>
00503     friend void
00504     __enable_shared_from_this_helper(const __shared_count<>& __pn,
00505                      const enable_shared_from_this* __pe,
00506                      const _Tp1* __px)
00507     {
00508       if (__pe != 0)
00509         __pe->_M_weak_assign(const_cast<_Tp1*>(__px), __pn);
00510     }
```

Answer (score 3):

This is defined inside the definition of `enable_shared_from_this`. Within the definition of a class template, the template name is also the injected class name, and can be used without qualification to refer to whichever specialisation is being instantiated.